# How to implement tasks in powershell based on a script parameter (i.e. msbuild, gradle)

Tags: powershell, build, scripting

Is it possible to implement a task-style system in PowerShell so that you could do the following:

```sh
.\script.ps1 build # runs build() function
.\script.ps1 publish # runs publish() function
```

I was hoping to use PowerShell for building/publishing an application rather than requiring the user to install gradle/msbuild and wanted to avoid needing to update a switch statement for every function added.

Currently it is messy like this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env powershell

param(
    $action = 'build'
)

function build() {
    echo 'build';
}

function publish() {
    echo 'publish';
}

switch($action) {
    'build' { build; }
    'publish' { publish; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), to execute a command (such as a function) whose *name* (or, in the case of commands that are external executables, *path*) is stored in a variable.

However, as [marsze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060966/marsze) points out, blindly invoking a function by name means that you could end up calling a command (of any form) that is *unrelated* to your script, which can be unintentional at best, and a security risk at worst.

Thankfully, PowerShell offers rich reflection capabilities and also exposes its own parsing API, so you can determine what functions are actually defined in the script itself, and only permit invocation of those.

Note that the code below also defines a `list` task, which lists the names of all tasks (functions) defined in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell

param(
  [string] $task = 'build'
)

# -- Define a function for each task.
#    Note that functions must be defined *before* they are called in PowerShell.

function list {
  "Available tasks:"
  $functionNames
}

function build {
  'build'
}

function publish {
  'publish'
}

# -- Invoke the specified task by invoking the function of the same name.

# Get the list of the names of all functions defined in this script.
$functionNames = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Ast.FindAll(
   { $args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] },
  $false
).Name

if ($task -in $functionNames) {

  # A known task - invoke it.
  & $task

}
else {

  # Report a script-terminating error, if the task name is uknown.
  throw "Unknown task: $task"
}
```

See also:

- [`System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast), the class that the script's [AST (abstract syntax tree)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), reported in `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock.Ast`, is an instance of.

Comment: I like it. And I agree, functions are of course still semantically much better to represent tasks. Amd the reflection solution is interesting. One reason I answer questions here is to extent my knowledge, and your contributions are always a valuable source.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @marsze, and I appreciate the nice feedback; your contributions similarly encourage me to dig deeper.

Comment: Brilliant solution, it's only a few lines and will let us add pseudo-tasks easily. It's a shame that you can't nominate an entry function out-of-the-box with PowerShell, it makes a great cross platform accepting language.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it is helpful, @Mangotastic. You can think of the top-level code in a script as an implicit function, but if you want an explicit one, you can do something like `function main { ... } main`, i.e. define a function and make the only line of top-level code the invocation of that function.